# Redirect overwrites different rules in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect (301) 900 URLs. I carefully made the whole list, without errors, but is behaves like a string replace. Take for example this line:

```
Redirect    301 /assortiment/artikelen_ingedeeld_per_branche/transporteurs_verhuisbedrijven3/Verhuisdekens____baal_a_25_stuks_.html?id=979 http://example.com/221-transport-en-verhuisbedrijven
```

And there is this line:

```
Redirect    301 /assortiment/   http://example.com/alle-producten
```

When I visit `/assortiment/artikelen_ingedeeld_per_branche/transporteurs_verhuisbedrijven3/Verhuisdekens____baal_a_25_stuks_.html?id=979` then it redirects to `/alle-productenartikelen_ingedeeld_per_branche/transporteurs_verhuisbedrijven3/Verhuisdekens____baal_a_25_stuks_.html?id=979`

Notic the `assortiment` --> `alle-producten` replacement at the beginning. As if it is rewritten like 'str_replace' I see what is happening, but I simply don't understand .htaccess well enough.

Answer (score 5):

The first redirect does nothing. You can't put the query string in a `Redirect`. The second is working as intended. The way `Redirect` works, is sort of a "starts with" approach. So if the directive is:

```
Redirect /a /b
```

then:

- `/a` will redirect to `/b`
- `/a/` will redirect to `/b/`
- `/abcd123` will redirect to `/bbcd123`
- `/a/b/c/d` will redirect to `/b/b/c/d`

Additionally, if your rule is:

```
Redirect /a/ /b
```

then:

- `/a/` will redirect to `/b`
- `/a/b/c/d` will redirect to `/bb/c/d`

etc.

If you don't want this to happen, then use redirect match:

```
RedirectMatch ^/assortiment/$   http://example.com/alle-producten
```

However, this isn't going to help with your query string. Neither `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` will match against the query string. You'll need to use mod_rewrite and rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=979$
RewriteRule ^assortiment/artikelen_ingedeeld_per_branche/transporteurs_verhuisbedrijven3/Verhuisdekens____baal_a_25_stuks_.html$ http://example.com/221-transport-en-verhuisbedrijven [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^assortiment/   http://example.com/alle-producten [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains it all. I have some work to do!

Comment: Please note that this example `/abcd123 will redirect to /bbcd123` is not true, it will not be redirected. With Redirect `Only complete path segments are matched`